# How can I call a method when someone scrolls beyond the top of a UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, scroll, uicollectionview

I am trying to add content 'above' the top of my UICollectionView and have the code call a method if the user scrolls up far enough.

It would be similar to 'pull to refresh' but I want it to present another view rather than refresh the data.

This behaviour is found in the 'Clear' app when you navigate 'up' and 'down' between the different lists.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit:
I found out how to add the content above using this:

```
UIView *topview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,-480,320,480)];
[self.tableView addSubview:topview];
```

Now I need to figure out how to respond to a user scrolling beyond the top of the collection view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you'll find that UICollectionView bases a lot off of UITableView. Have you tried leveraging methods similar to what the old self-made pull-to-refresh classes did? Something along the lines of:

```
if (isDragging && scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0)
```